# My SelectList based on an enum cannot update the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple Html.DropDownList that is backed by a SelectList which, in turn, is backed by my enum.

```
Enum Colors
Red=1,
Green,
Blue
```

I add an option label to my Html.DropDownList that shows "Please select..."

The problem is when I post this page and the value is "Please select..." (int value=0) and do an UpdateModel I get an error saying, "The ViewModel was not successfully updated."

Is there any way around this?

Comment: An enum is 0 by default. Maybe you could assign all values to your enumerations. Add 'None = 0' and add validation to your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not allow posting unless it is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Use a nullable enum in the Controller method or ViewModel. When 0 is selected you can use:

```
Model.Color.HasValue
```

to check if a value has been set.